# VBA FormulaR1C1 RC expression is not working when used with division

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba. I try to put a formula into a range which works well, but the formula is troubling me. I feel the issue might be because of the division.. maybe the slash is a kind of escaping character?

Here the code:

```
MyWorksheet.Range("J7","J12").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[0]C[-1]/R0C1 *100"
```

and it gives me this in excel:

```
=I7/R0C1 *100
```

So R0C1 is not replaced :-(. How comes? and how can I fix this?
I have goggled a lot but I did not find anything similar.. so hopefully I am not the only one with this issue.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: `R0C1` is incorrect absolute reference (zeroth row) (`$A$0`).

Comment: Ah.. got it! I have corrected it to R13C9..  Now it is working fine! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the zero in your formula - when using absolute reference (i.e. omitting brackets) in `R1C1`-notation, you count from an imaginary cell one up and one left of `A1` - in other words, cell `A1` is `R1C1` in that notation, `B2` is `R2C2`, etc.

And `R0C1` does not exist, thus why it is interpreted as a string in your formula.

Comment: yes, thank you very much! I have corrected it to R13C9  - the cell I actually wanted to point to. I guess i was code-blind  ;-)